Blender Thumbnails not showing in windows file explorer?
I am using blender 3.6 at the moment right now and I followed these steps in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYdNOggfSwg
But I am not seeing any blender file thumbnails, just the icon.
I do believe this is a windows issue because it works perfect for my friend, so it's something with my computer.


Blender needs to be registered in your system to generate thumbnails. This is done automatically when installing with the executable installer file. But any other kind of installation (portable, zips, Steam, ...) need to be registered manually.
Manual registration is done using a command line.
Open the command prompt where your Blender.exe is, type blender -R and press enter. It should register that Blender application in your system and trigger thumbnailing of .blend files in the file explorer.
See Command Line - Blender 4.1 Manual for more about Blender's CLI.
If you use Blender Launcher, just  RMB the build you want to register, and hit Register Extension.

You might also need to enable thumbnails in Windows if it doesn't display thumbnails for anything.
Search Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows in the start menu, and from there make sure Show thumbnails instead of icons is enabled.


i have tried to do the CMD blender -R thing in my blender.exe path but it did not work, do i have to run CMD as admin for this to work?

Maybe. It might also require rebooting so to refresh the file explorer. Also make sure thumbnails are enable in your system to begin with.

i cannot reboot my computer because it is doing a task that is not resume-able at the moment, i did check if thumbnails are enabled which they are and i also restarted file explorer and so far nothing has worked unfortunately
